# Migrating a self referencing table using Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a table which has 2 colums.

```
Id - Primarky key
Parent ID - Foreign key populated by the value above (Id).
```

(So basically the FK is in the same table)
When I migrate this, I get the following error.
"The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint"
Please let me know how to deal with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the foreign key constraint first.  Then migrate your data.  And afterwards you can enable the constraint again.

```
ALTER TABLE Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader  
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_PurchaseOrderHeader_Employee_EmployeeID; 


ALTER TABLE Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader  
CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_PurchaseOrderHeader_Employee_EmployeeID;
```

[Disable foreign key constraints with INSERT and UPDATE statements](https://Disable%20foreign%20key%20constraints%20with%20INSERT%20and%20UPDATE%20statements)